# Accessing the element of an array at negative index

Tags: c, arrays

I have this function:

```
void func(int index, struct foo b[])
{
    // ...
    a[0][0] = b[index].c[0];
    // ...
}
```

but sometimes the function is called with index `-2`:

```
a[0][0] = b[-2].c[0];
```

I think -2 is out of bounds, it crash sometimes, but sometimes it doesn't.

If the head address of array b is 0xffd9cda4, what's the addess of b[-2]?
0xffd9cda4 + 0xfffffffe = 0x1ffd9cda2? Is 0x1ffd9cda2 valid?

It's running on Linux 64bit.

Comment: You *think* -2 is out of bounds?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: What is the type of `b`?  If it is an array like you (vaguely) say, then the question is moot.  If not, show us more code.  How is it declared?  Is it initialized or assigned to?

Answer (score 2):

You have an array `b` that occupies the memory block that starts at the address `&b[0]`. Don't even try to find out what's the address of `b[-2]`, because this is obviously not within the memory block occupied by this array.

Trying to access the memory outside array bounds produces **undefined behavior**.

---

Also note that it is not possible to retrieve the size of the array `b` within the body of this function:

```
void func(int index, struct foo b[]) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Accessing an array outside its bounds results in undefined behavior. However, C does not have automatic array bounds checking. So this might cause a crash, but there's no guarantee that it will. Often it just overflows into some object that just happens to be located adjacent in memory.

Note that if `b` is a pointer, not an array, then `b[-2]` may be valid. E.g.

```
typedef struct foo {
   int c[5];
} foo_struct;
foo_struct x[10];
foo_struct *b = &x[3];
```

If you now do:

```
a[0][0] = b[-2].c[0];
```

it's equivalent to doing:

```
a[0][0] = x[1].c[0];
```

The relevant array bounds in this case are those of `x`.

Comment: *"accessing an array with an invalid index (either negative or too high) might cause a crash, but there's no guarantee that it will"* - but it is guaranteed by the standard that doing such a thing produces **undefined behavior**, thus should be avoided.

Comment: @LihO I was trying to answer his question about why it crashes sometimes, but not always.

Comment: Yes I understand. I just think there should be some disclaimer that clearly states, that he can't rely on accessing the memory this way.

Comment: @LihO I thought that was clear when I said it's an "invalid index".

Comment: @Barmar Good answer, but I agree that it would be better to explicitly include the words "undefined behaviour". ("... invalid index (...) is undefined behaviour, it might cause ..." or something)

Answer (score 0):

```
b[-2]
```

Is the same as

```
*(b - 2)
```

Which is just as obviously wrong.  Undefined behavior, accessing memory you don't own.  UB doesn't mean your program will crash, it means that *the behavior of your program is undefined*.

Comment: @casper1314: I have no idea what you mean by that.

Comment: The scenario is
void func(int index, struct foo b[])
{
   ...
   a[0][0] = b[index].c[0];
   ... 
}
Sometimes the function was called with index = -2;
Sometime it crash, sometimes it may not. And I need to tell testers how to reproduce it and then try if my fix is effective.

When running to the line, seeing from IDE that, b: 0xffd9cda4, index: 0xfffffffe(-2).
Then I want to see which memory range b[index] went to and see if I can find some regular steps to reproduce it.

How do you say?

Comment: @casper1314: It is *undefined behavior*.  You cannot always cause it to crash.  Period. You have now (well we have) diagnosed the issue.  The fix is to stop accessing outside the bounds of the array and test to the spec.  If you really need to go further then log the index and reproduce the situation which caused an invalid index to be passed in, ensuring invalid indices do not appear in the log.